# Is it possible to use multiple version of QT in a project

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I'm trying to build the [Guided Hacking DLL injector](https://github.com/Broihon/GH-Injector-GUI) I've installed qt and the versions it requires but I cant get it to build. in the read me file

```
5. Setup MSVC
    1. Toolbar -> Qt VS Tools -> Qt Options -> Add ->
        1. "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019"
        2. "C:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64"
        3. "C:\Qt\5.15.2\qt-5.15.2-static-msvc2019-x86_64"
    2. Toolbar -> Project -> Properties -> Qt Project Settings -> Qt Installation -> 
        1. x86 -> msvc2019
        2. x64 -> msvc2019_64
        3. x64_static -> qt-5.15.2-static-msvc2019-x86_64
    3. Restart MSVC to repair intellisense
    4. Build project
```

I see all these appear but i can only select one QT installation at a time and I get different errors with each version

I'm expecting a version the gui injector to build a working exe file, I've tried each version of QT changing other properties settings. I think I need to select all the versions of qt at the same time but im not sure how to do it

Comment: Those are all (presumably) the **same** version, just for different targets. If you are getting errors, it's useful to show those errors in the question. Also make sure to take the [tour] and read [ask].